# PHP echo not showing before CURL request

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest, curl

My problem is that i have a script that is using curl however i want to sent a reply message before the curl request id done. However the script does not show the echo until the request is completed.

I am using codeigniter with the rest client add on

```
<?php 
function test(){
 echo 'Your request is being generated';
 $body='some data';
 $this->load->library('rest', array('server' => 'https://api.server.com'));
 $this->rest->http_header('Authorization', 'secret key' );
 $this->rest->post('/create',json_encode($body) , 'json' );
}
```

As the POST request can take up to a minute plus long, i am trying to send some kind of respond back to the client app so that the app would be notified that the request is being process and they can leave the page.

Do note that as this is a backend API system i must post some sort of respond if not, my phone app would hang while it waits for a respond.

Comment: It won't do the echo right away because it's in the same function? It will show the echo after the WHOLE function is finished or am I wrong? Maybe you should make an echo right before you call that function?

Comment: Nope you suggestion didn't work for me. Even if i did an ECHO before calling this test function. The echo would not show.

Comment: Have you checked error reporting is enabled, and you are not getting errors? That might be a cause of an echo not displaying

Comment: Hi Daryl, i have checked error reporting is enabled. There is no errors showing up with my code. I am wondering whether it is a PHP process that ECHOs would only be shown after curl request finishes and it does not matter if the echo was place before the request?

Comment: PHP does not stream the output to the client. You need to finish your processing then send a full response. Technically note, php can stream data as it builds up a buffer of output.

Comment: I see.  How then can I work around this , so I can show an output while letting the process finish

Comment: As I mention , I do not have webpages. This script is all for an api I am building therefore JavaScript cannot be done.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't read that

Answer (score 1):

When using CodeIgniter all the output are going to output buffer and then flushed to the browser. I think better idea will be to load the page in a different function and CURL in different function. In the main function simply load the view with loading icon and then through AJAX call the second function to initiate the CURL action and display the output from the CURL.

Comment: I see , but as my codes is also for an api server I cannot do an Ajax as there is no website page. All of my reply goes directly to an iPhone app in a Json format